# Cause of Oblique Pain

Tags: injury

When my wife gets done with a long ride she finds that her right oblique hurts, while her left does not.  Does anyone know a possible cause of this, like improper form or saddle fit?

Comment: I'd suspect that her "reach" distance is not right, maybe exacerbated by some slight scoliosis.  Nobody's perfectly symmetrical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be a number of things:

- Saddle/cleat/handle bar misalignment
- bad form on her right side, not spinning circles, etc

Have you ridden with her and checked out her form? Is she favoring one side over the other?

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles!